# Составное именное сказуемое -это словосочетание или нет?

Tags: синтаксис

например, люблю читать - это словосочетание?

Answer (score 5):

Меня тоже всегда интересовал этот вопрос. Спасибо.
В составном глагольном сказуемом вспомогательный и основной глагол действительно связаны по типу примыкание. Это так называемое **несвободное словосочетание - *"соединение слов, в котором грамматически зависимое слово является главным по смыслу, а грамматически главное слово является недостаточным с точки зрения семантики (информации)**. Синтаксически несвободные словосочетания не разлагаются на составные части. В предложении синтаксически цельные словосочетания являются одним членом предложения: два дома, несколько студентов, мало времени.."*

**Модели несвободных (цельных) словосочетаний:**

1. Количественно-именные словосочетания.
2. Словосочетания со значением избирательности.
3. Словосочетания с метафорическим значением.
4. Словосочетания со значением неопределённости.
5. Словосочетания со значением совместности.
6. Контекстуально-цельные словосочетания.

***7. Словосочетания в составных сказуемых, включающие в себя вспомогательные глаголы, глаголы-связки или другие вспомогательные компоненты: Он начал рассказывать о приключениях в джунглях Амазонки; Мы хотим вам помочь; Она выглядела усталой.*** [Здесь](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=79f079b0-5d1e-4e30-8670-c117e48da245)

Comment: Так словосочетание или нет?

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению:

1) "Люблю читать." равносильно [предложению] "Я люблю читать.",

2) "Любим писать." равносильно [предложению] "Мы любим писать.".

Comment: Ну и что, что равносильно?

Comment: Добавил надлежащее слово в свой ответ.